# How to simulate highlight text for mobile devices on Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm curious if it's possible to simulate highlight text on "touchstart" via Chrome Dev Tools instead of testing directly on phone.

I tried mobile view but the touch icon doesn't seem to highlight the text when I drag it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: FWIW there are phone emulators.

Comment: I forgot to mention my computer crashes/hangs when using phone emulators. :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This level of detail isn't available within Device Mode. You'd need to use an emulator.

Device Mode is only meant to provide the upper 85-90% of what most developers will need to test their web applications. It is not meant to handle everything (as that highlight UX is platform-specific) nor is it meant to replace actual device testing.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old question, But instead of an emulator now we can use chrome's new feature [Remote Debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/).

**Here are steps:**

1. [Enable Developer Options](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options) - To enable tap **Build Number** 7 times

```
Settings > About Phone > Build Number
```

*The above location may vary depending on your Android version.*

2. [Enable USB Debugging](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options)

```
Settings > System > Developer Options > USB debugging
```

3. Connect your mobile device to your computer using USB cable and tap **OK**
   to allow *USB debugging*.
4. Open `chrome://inspect/#devices` and in the **Remote Target** section check whether your device is listed, if not make sure to unlock your device.
5. In the **Devices** section, click **Port forwarding** and enter your website port(*e.g: 8080*) and then in the next field enter IP and port(*e.g: localhost:8080*)
6. Open chrome on your mobile and goto **localhost:8080**

**You can still use chrome devtools to debug, simply click on inspect in the Remote Target section.**